# How can we catch a mind controller

Tags: internal-consistency, government, mind-control

**Some Background**

The government is very good at catching people. Even the few who can keep away from them are forced into a life of running. But there is a new threat that the worlds governments face together, Alexander. Native to Greece and on a anarchic wave of crime, **-** causing car accidents and breaking into bank vaults **-** Alexander has managed to complete his tasks without even slight struggle. The current theory is that he has mind controlling abilities. The united nations agreed that he must be stopped. They have requested the help of Earth's greatest minds to come up with a solution.

**A Few Details of Alexander**

- Before learning of his abilities Alexander was a pilot.
- Alexander can only mind control people if he can see the shape of their head

### The Rules

1. The Governments have become desperate and are willing to spend whatever it takes to bring Alexander into custody.
2. They do not want to kill Alexander, they just want to bring him into custody.
3. The solution cannot result in any human casualties.

---

Using the above information how can the governments of Earth catch a person who can mind control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Hire him.

Failing that, fool him. Run a media campaign to instigate a local conflict that hits close to home for him. While he's occupied, infiltrate his circles with people who know nothing about your mission and think that this all is being done for the good of their homeland.

Or simply hire him as a mercenary to do some innocious-looking-dirty-job for undisclosed governmental agency. Considering his methods, he's not really a bright fellow.

When you have his coordinates (preferrably in advance) you rig the whole place with remote controlled means of subduing - be it gas, a lot of syringes with sedatives, something like that. Keep him drugged as long as you need to transport him to a facility built specifically for him.

> The solution cannot result in any human casualties.

This looks strange though. Requirement to take hostile aircraft carrier without any human casualities looks *a bit unreasonable*. Not sure how high-profile target this fellow is, but if he's an international trouble, then some collaterals would usually be allowed.

> Alexander can only mind control people whose head he can see

Can't be sure though. Maybe it's a hoax to keep something up his sleeve and will turn out to be false in critical moment. Assuming that he can control anyone in some generous radius would be fine I guess. If he's capable of more than that, capturing him alive is way riskier.

Answer (score 4):

If they have already identified and tracked him it would be relatively easy.

Shoot him from long range with a tranquilizer dart.

Or a higher tech option would be a drone strike or other air delivered munitions dispersing a knockout gas to the nearby area.

Basically anything that puts him to sleep or otherwise incapacitates him at a distance would work.

Answer (score 4):

*Alexander can only mind control people whose head he can see*

So he's a 2 bagger and you're good to go.

For those who don't know what that means, you put a bag on your head so he can't see you and a bag on his head in case yours comes off.

(traditionally some of those words are in a slightly different order)

Comment: I should have been more clear, if he can see your head as in the shape

Comment: @TrEs-2b, that just requires a larger more shapeless bag

Answer (score 1):

Four questions, which may provide possible answers:

1. how long-range is his power? you identified that he can control the minds of anyone's head that he can see, so therefore (in theory) he would be able to control the minds of the government agents who come in contact with him - but from what distance? it might be interesting to see if his power decreases over a certain area.
2. how are they keeping track of him? due the question above, wouldn't they be afraid of him? are they using long-distance trackers of some kind?
3. how large is his "anarchic wave of crime"? if you can identify that, perhaps we can identify possible motives for why each particular country wants to catch Alexander so badly and who would, therefore, catch him first. (Depending on their relative level of desperation.)
4. what would they do after they catch Alexander, if they did? who's to say he wouldn't escape and start the wave of crime all over again? what are the motives of the "Earth's greatest minds"? why do they not want to kill him, but merely trap/incarcerate him?

That's all.