# Killing a mind controller

Tags: modern-age, mind-control, assassination

Bill has a special power: he can create any kind of sensory hallucination on anyone that gets near him (about 1 km range).

The hallucination can be as complex as he wants it to be, and it doesn't require him to pay attention to its victim (it can be a completely passive effect, like making everyone see an empty bed instead of him sleeping).

Assuming no sniping (he lives in a city so there is no way to get a clear sight on him without entering his powers range) and no carpet bombing, what would be the best way to kill (or at least capture) him?

This is fairly similar to [Assassinate a semi-omniscient crime lord](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/68481/assassinate-a-semi-omniscient-crime-lord), but there are a few key differences:

1. He's not omniscent. He doesn't know how many people are in his powers range, or what they are doing
2. He can only act directly on those that he knows are there. If he doesn't know someone is near him, only his passive powers work
3. He doesn't have huge financial capabilities, though he could trick cops to protect him with some complex hallucination
4. As soon as he notices someone, he can make him visualize/hear/percieve whatever he wants

EDIT: everyone is assuming he's a villain, but he's not. He just wants to live a normal life, but is chased down by the government/special forces, and has to resort to self-defense tricks like making himself invisible to everyone but those he's talking to.

Comment: It's more like [how to catch a mind controller](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/50709/how-can-we-catch-a-mind-controller)

Comment: This reminds me of a certain infamous [villain](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/S%C5%8Dsuke_Aizen) in the manga Bleach.

Comment: @Separatrix I saw that question, however his powers are fairly different

Comment: @NotAVampire I thought about him while writing the question. However, it is based on a videogame character (that I will not name due to spoilers)

Comment: In accordance with discussion [here](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/4317/6986), voting to close as too broad.

Comment: He can just passively make everyone not be able to see him, and he can lead a life all alone from everyone. You're going to have to provide some more information about his personality. Also what did he do for you to want to kill him?

Comment: Why do you assume no sniping just because he lives in a city? While the shooter would be within range of his powers, it's reasonable to assume that a not-omniscient Bill wouldn't be able to notice a hidden shooter until after he's shot. E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D._C._sniper_attacks were performed from ~100 yards, and the victims and anyone near them didn't notice the shooter.

Comment: YAOV - Yet another overpowered villain. :(

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. The number of ways to kill such a person is very large.

Comment: I just realized the question would be better if inverted. As in: "How does he minimize the chances of being killed/captured, given his powers and that special forces are on his track?" However there already is an answer and I don't know if I should edit the question to better match this new interpretation

Comment: If the mind-controller looks like The Doctor and starts yelling "JESSICA!," I think you can just walk up to him. ;)

Comment: @BgrWorker Maybe just ask it as a different question. IMHO this character is not automatically overpowered. You don't really go into what his passive powers are as mentioned in step 2, but it seems like he's pretty limited on what he can do if he has to know about a person in order to manipulate them. Granted, he could still be overpowered if he decided to be bad and used it as an offensive weapon. It just isn't great as a defensive weapon... So if you decide to open a new question, that would be one area to focus on.

Answer (score 12):

### Use a discreet drone

A drone can be operated from more than a kilometer, it doesn't get hallucinations, it can carry weaponry/explosives/gas and can stay unnoticed until the last moment.

### Get his trust

Bill can influence people's perception, but he can't know their intent. As you can't stay alone your all life, everybody needs some sort of companionship. Someone attractive and a dose of poison is all you need!

Comment: One word. Ninja Assassin. Okay two words but it's a ninja assassin.

Comment: @Snowlockk It's also redundant, since Ninja implies Assassin =P

Comment: @SouthpawHare could be a ninja scout, ninja medic or even a ninja sushi chef........... :)

Comment: @Snowlockk - I hired a ninja sushi chef once. The bastard never showed up for work. 0/10 would not recommend.

Comment: @amflare How do you know he didn't show up?

Answer (score 4):

## His power only works while you're in range.

Bill is human(ish), Bill presumably wants to live some kind of life and leaves some kind of trail if special forces are after him. Perhaps he likes living in one area, perhaps he occasionally has 1 night stands with people he meets at a few clubs, whatever. We can assume he's not a total ghost.

**Bills power does not work on video cameras.**

So, stake out the locations that you think he might be, push everything through video cameras and have people a few miles away watching the footage in real time.

He's also visible on public CCTV so he can be tracked.

If your goal is to kill him simply wire his home up with explosives and video cameras while he's out for a walk. When he walks in the door verify he's the target and hit the button.

If bombing is not practical then alternative options include poisoning his cheerios, gassing him or filling his socks drawer with scorpions.

**Simply killing seems a little to easy**

There's even the option of flooding the room with riot foam if you want him probably-alive.

[image: riot foam]

**Capture**

Concealed canisters jet riot foam in every direction covering Bill.

A speaker comes to life and informs Bill that if he does not comply there's a second, lethal trap that will be triggered. They are watching him on camera, he must not use his power and must allow agents to enter and place a collar on him. He is being watched by many cameras.

The collar includes cameras, tacking and an explosive charge that can be detonated by his handler who is several thousand miles away.

The special forces just caught themselves an agent who can walk past almost any guard post who can be managed remotely.

Answer (score 2):

Based on 1 and 2, he can only act on people that he knows are coming for him.
He lives in the middle of a city, so there are thousands of people around all the time. Someone that is trained in observing without being noticed would be able to keep tabs on him, observe his routines, and get close enough to act fairly easily.

Unless the guy is paranoid enough to go around without being seen constantly, he's going to be vulnerable to people just walking by him. As long as they don't draw attention to themselves they could brush by him in the crowd, give him an injection to knock him out, tie him up and take him to a lab or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

## Give him a choice

If he's not a bad guy, don't try and kill him right off the bat.  Get him to talk to you and get things sorted out peacefully.

If he doesn't trust you, then use containment and evacuate the city.  Place remote controlled gates around the perimeter and ask everyone to leave the area for their own good.

Once he's the only one left, feel free to send in a heat-seeker equipped drone and zap him with tranquiliser darts.

Whatever choice he makes, lock him in a room with a 1km gap between him and anyone else and serve him his meals on a model train....

Answer (score 0):

One of these. Control it remotely. Kill him or capture him with it.

[image]

Comment: Lol not overkill at all. Nuke would be cheaper.